# How to prove the validity of $¬∃x P(x) ⊢ ∀x ¬P(x)$ in predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I think that I need to assume $¬∀x ¬P(x)$ and then do a proof by contradiction but I am not sure if that is correct or how to go about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need contradiction in the proof (but it is not a poof by contradiction) :

1) $\lnot \exists x \ Px$ --- premise

2) $\quad\quad| \quad Px$ --- assumed [a]

3) $\quad\quad| \quad \exists x \ Px$ --- from 2) by [$\exists$-intro](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7)

4) $\quad\quad| \quad\bot$ --- *contradiction!* from 1) and 3)

5) $\lnot Px$ --- from 2)-4) by [$\lnot$-intro](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4), discharging [a]

> 6) $\forall x \ \lnot Px$ --- from 5) by [$\forall$-intro](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7).

Comment: Would steps 2-4 be a subproof? If I make that a subproof and assume $[a]P(a)$ then step 5 - $¬Px$ is not a sentence.

Comment: In step 5 I am not able to cite steps 2 and 4. I have to select the whole sub proof which doesn't work.

Comment: @DarynWilkinson - you can freely modify the proof to adapt it to your needs... :-)

Comment: ∀-intro needs a sub proof cited. I can't just reference step 5.

Comment: @DarynWilkinson The subproof is the introduction of an arbitrary element $c$, for which is proven must be $\neg Pc$.

Comment: $\neg$-intro is not the same as proof by contradiction.

Comment: Negation introduction: $\dfrac{\Gamma, P\vdash \bot}{\Gamma \vdash \neg P}$. Proof by contradiction: $\dfrac{\Gamma , \neg P\vdash \bot}{\Gamma\vdash P}$.  So indeed similar, but not quite the same. (There's a double negation elimination in the latter).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof for that in Fitch. Exact same idea as Mauro's proof but it does not have free variables anywhere which, it seems, your proof system does not want either:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have for *any* proposition $Q$ not containing $x$ free, $(\exists x.P(x))\to Q\vdash \forall x.(P(x)\to Q)$. This is constructively true. Assume $P(c)$ for some arbitrary $c$, then use modus ponens on the assumption after introducing an existential, then generalize as $c$ is arbitrary. As a lambda term, it is basically currying. If you choose $Q\equiv\bot$, you get your statement using the fact that (even constructively) $\neg P\equiv P\to \bot$.